# Group by with CLOB in select-statement

Tags: sql, oracle

My select-statement looks like:

```
Select column1, column2
From Table1
Group By column2
```

`column1` is a CLOB and I want to receive one of the values that is part of one group. I know they are all the same so it doesn't matter which one I get. I've tried functions like `MIN` and `MAX` but they don't accept CLOB as a type.

To be clear I don't want to aggregate the CLOBs just pick one of them.

This is a simplification of the actual SELECT statement and the GROUP BY clause is necessary.

So with this data:

```
column1       column2
qwerty          1
qwerty          1
asdfgh          2
asdfgh          2
```

I want to get:

```
qwerty          1
asdfgh          2
```

Any idea how this could be done?

Comment: You can try using `DBMS_CRYPTO` to generate a hash of the `CLOB` column and group on the hash and then use a self-join to get the `CLOB` value again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `CLOB` value cannot be used for grouping or inside a `distinct` clause.

The only chance you have is to convert the `CLOB` to a varchar but that means you cannot compare the complete contents of the column (note: those are *columns*, not rows). If you are certain that all your CLOB values are smaller than 8000 bytes, you can use something like this:

```
select min(dbms_lob.substr(column1)), column2
from foo
group by column2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub-queries. 
Add unique column ID and then:

```
SELECT t1.col2,t2.col1
  FROM 
      (SELECT max(ID) as IDM, col2 FROM Table1 GROUP BY col2) t1 
  LEFT JOIN 
      Table1 t2
      ON t1.IDM=t2.ID
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I get two rows and I cant use DISTINCT because of the CLOB

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT row1, row2 FROM Table1;
```

Comment: You can't use `DISTINCT` with a `CLOB` column.